# Passenger on Bluehost doesn't see the correct Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, ruby-on-rails-4, bluehost

I followed number of instruction how to install latest ruby versions on Bluehost, and managed to get Ruby-2.0.0-p195 with Rails-4.0.0-rc1. Pretty much I get full functionality with ability to run irb and download gem files.

```
bash [~/rails/sample/config]# ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]
bash [~/rails/sample/config]# rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.rc1
bash [~/rails/sample/config]# which ruby
/home6/username/ruby/bin/ruby
bash [~/rails/sample/config]# which rails
/home6/username/ruby/gems/bin/rails
```

I was able to create an empty application just to test if it runs. My .htaccess file loos like this:

```
bash [~/rails/sample/config]# more ~/www/sample/.htaccess 
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
RailsEnv production
RackBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /home6/username/rails/sample
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home6/username/ruby/gems
bash [~/rails/sample/config]#
```

My .bashrc file looks like this:

```
bash [~]# more ~/.bashrc 
# .bashrc

export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib64/ruby/gem/1.8
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$HOME/ruby/gems/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/ruby/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/node/bin:$PATH
```

When I visit my page (www.somedomain.com/sample) I get following error with passenger:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

The application has exited during startup (i.e. during the evaluation of config/environment.rb). 
The error message can be found below. To solve this problem, please follow any instructions in the
error message.

Error message: Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.0. You're running ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770  
on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, uby Enterprise Edition 2012.02 Please upgrade to Ruby 
1.9.3 or newer to continue.

Application root: /home6/username/rails/sample

Backtrace:    
0   /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/ruby_version_check.rb   Line 3  in `abort'
1   /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/ruby_version_check.rb   Line 3  
2   /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails.rb  Line 1  in `require'
3   /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails.rb  Line 1  
4   /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/all.rb  Line 1  in `require'
5   /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/all.rb  Line 1  
6   /home6/username/rails/sample/config/application.rb  Line 3  in `require'
7   /home6/username/rails/sample/config/application.rb  Line 3  
8   /home6/username/rails/sample/config/environment.rb  Line 2  in `require'
9   /home6/username/rails/sample/config/environment.rb  Line 2  
10  config.ru   Line 3  in `require'
11  config.ru   Line 3  
12  /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb   Line 55 in `instance_eval'
13  /home6/username/ruby/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb   Line 55 in `initialize'
14  config.ru   Line 1  in `new'
15  config.ru   Line 1
```

Why the passenger is still looking for an old ruby and doesn't see the new installation? Or is it the rails issue? Is there a way to make it use the right one? Did I miss something somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated.

Pavel.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the server is not running Phusion Passenger 4. Multiple Ruby versions is only supported since Phusion Passenger 4.0.0, as is support for reading environment variables from bashrc. The server is currently running some 3.x version.

Comment: What if I install my own passenger? `#[~] gem install passenger
Fetching: passenger-4.0.5.gem (100%)`. Installation went well: `[~]# passenger -v       Phusion Passenger version 4.0.5` . The pass to the passenger is `[~]# which passenger =>
/home6/username/ruby/gems/bin/passenger`   . I mean, there were people able to upgrade the default ruby/rails to Ruby-1.9.3 and Rails-3.2.x. I haven't heard much about this issue, even though google search is my friend.

Comment: If you have sufficient access to the system then you can upgrade Phusion Passenger.

Comment: I only have an access to my user folder: /home6/username/. I can only do things on my level. For example, ruby2.0 runs only in my folder home settings. I have latest node.js installed on my side as well. No body has root privileges on the shared hosting.

Comment: Then the best thing you can do then is running Passenger Standalone with `passenger start`.